# Sharing data between two powershell scripts

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have two scripts namely, Add and Report. I am having a array of items in Add script. I want to read this array in Report script. Add script can be called multiple times. I want to retain the value in array and read them in Report script. I have added Persistent Session ID to both these scripts. How do I update the array list in Add script whenever the add script is called and read the array list in Report script.
I have a global function where I have initialized the class,

```
class Modes {
    [string]$ItemId
    [string]$InstallMode
    [string]$MergeMode
}
[Modes[]]$itemModes = @()
```

In Add.script,

```
foreach($item in $selectedItems){
                    
                    $itemMode= [Modes]@{
                    ItemId =  (Get-Item $item).Name
                    InstallMode= $installModeOption
                    MergeMode =  $mergeModeOption
                    }
                    $itemModes =[Array] $itemModes +  $itemMode
}
```

In Report.script

```
$itemModes|Show-ListView
```

How do I read the itemsModes I have added in Add.script in Report.script?

Comment: When you try to access the $itemModes, in another script, did you get any error? Because I created two scripts. In the first one, I assigned a list of items to a variable, and when I access that in another script it shows the output.

Comment: Hi Sumit, I think this line is causing the issue,ItemId =  (Get-Item $item).Name. I need to get the ID of each item. Bt this is not working as expected. So error is thrown

Comment: If you are getting $item in foreach loop then why you are trying to use Get-Item? Can't you just use $item.Name?

Comment: Initially I tried with this one. It was throwing some error. So I used Get-Item. Now I have updated it to $item.Name. it's working fine and error is now gone.

Comment: So did it resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes.. it solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this discussion, When you have items in your `$selectedItems` and then in the loop, you are again trying to call `Get-Item` is creating the issue. You just need to update

```
ItemId =  (Get-Item $item).Name
```

To

```
ItemId =  $item.Name
```

And it will solve your issue.